# Distance to the image of a continuous linear mapping over a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. $A: H \rightarrow H$ is linear and continuous, $x \in H$ and r is a real number s.t. $r>\text{dist}(x,A(H))$. Show that there exists a unique $y_0 \in H$ such that:

1. $\|x-A(y_0)\| \leq r$
2. $\|y_0\|=\inf\{\|y\|: y\in H, \|x-A(y)\| \leq r\}$.

Can $\inf$ be substituted with $\min$?

My attempt at solution:

Since $A$ is linear it is easy to show that $A(H)$ is convex. We use the theorem of distance to convex sets in Hilbert spaces to show that for $x$ there exists a unique $a \in A(H)$ such that $\|x-a\| = \text{dist}(x,A(H))$. If this is a good point to start, how do I show that $a$ has a unique inverse image using the properties provided in the problem?

Comment: don't you think you should revise the second condition for $y_0$?

Comment: this was just a typo. thanks for the edit.

Comment: How do you know that the range of $A$ is closed? (If you are using the distance to convex set approach.)

Comment: It is not true that there is a unique $a \in {\cal R}A$ such that $\|x-a\| = \operatorname{dist}(a, {\cal R}A)$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2515439/27978 for an example where there is a $y$ in the closure of the range but not in the range.

Comment: @copper.hat yeah, I indeed forgot that it has to be closed.